Numpy Einsum - Why did this happen?
Can you explain why this happened?
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2],
              [3,4],
              [5,6]
              ])
b = np.array([[2,2,2],
              [2,2,2]])
print(np.einsum("xy,zx -> yx",a,b))

and output of the code is:[[ 4 12 20] [ 8 16 24]]  Which means the answer is calculated like this : ‍‍[1*2+1*2 , 3*2+3*2 , ...] 
But I expected it to be calculated like this: [[1*2 , 3*2 , 5*2],[2*2 , 4*2 , 6*2]] Where did I make a mistake?

So, you're asking why "xy,zx->yx" doesn't give you the same result as "xy,yx->yx" when z=y?

z appears only once, so it is summed.
